# Android app with Parse SDK - need for SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, google-app-engine, parse-platform

I need to create an Android app that performs the cloud sync with the data.
 I came across Parse SDK (BaaS) and tried some sample app. 
Now, for providing features like local data storage during offline use and syncing up whenever network is available, I was wondering weather we have to use Local SQLite DB.
 But I noticed Parse provides 'Local Data Store' feature as well.
https://www.parse.com/tutorials/using-the-local-datastore 
So is it necessary to use SQLite in the app then?
What are all the cons if are sticking to Parse and avoiding SQLite.

Comment: No, Parse, in all likelihood, is a SQL service. They host databases on their service which you can alter with simple API commands. As for local data storage, how is that any different from writing and reading from a local file. My point is every service is based on another underlying service.

Comment: yes...I understand parse is inturn a SQL service...so must not be a problem in sticking with parse local data store....cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my app.

What i found out that SQLite is faster than parse's local storage, and a bit more stable. Also plus is that you can encrypt SQLite databases.

I dont remember now exactly what happened, but i think there were some crashes related to local storage. Also it didnt work as expected. On some devices the parse local storage was very slow.

In general i would recommend using SQLite. Also there are some architectural problems that cant be solved with Parse's local storage. Those pin and saveInBackground methods were not so transparent to me, so i ended up using SQLite instead.

There were different frameworks for SQLite, but i couldn't get my head into them and ended using SQLite without frameworks, which turned out to be easy.

Comment: I can understand...but instead I started using 'DreamFactory' opensource framework which can be used with our own amazon servers, rather than relying on Parse's server. Its always good to have the server in our control. I would highly recommend it for a cloud based app....cheers.